# Pre-ordered traversal of a balanced binary tree

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I'm doing a pre-ordered traversal over a balanced tree made from a sorted array and I'm not getting the results I expected.

I've done a lot of research on the matter and this is a last resort kind of thing. I've tried different variations of traversals (post, and in-order) which have not yielded the expected outputs. Code below.

```
import sys


class Node:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


# function to convert sorted array to a
# balanced BST
# input : sorted array of integers
# output: root node of balanced BST
def sort_array_to_bst(arr):
    if not arr:
        return None

    # find middle
    mid = (len(arr)) / 2
    mid = int(mid)

    # make the middle element the root
    root = Node(arr[mid])

    # left subtree of root has all
    # values <arr[mid]
    root.left = sort_array_to_bst(arr[:mid])

    # right subtree of root has all
    # values >arr[mid]
    root.right = sort_array_to_bst(arr[mid + 1:])
    return root


# A utility function to print the pre-order
# traversal of the BST
def pre_order(node):
    if not node:
        return
    if root:

        sys.stdout.write(str(node.data) + ' ')
        pre_order(node.left)
        #sys.stdout.write(str(node.data) + ' ')
        pre_order(node.right)
        #sys.stdout.write(str(node.data) + ' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = []
    for line in sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" "):
        arr.append(line)
    # arr = [7, 898, 157, 397, 57, 178, 26, 679]
    # Expected Output = 178 57 26 157 679 397 898
    narr = arr[1:]
    narr.sort()
    root = sort_array_to_bst(narr)
    pre_order(root)
```

The array being entered in via stdin is `7 898 157 397 57 178 26 679`, and the expected output is `178 57 26 157 679 397 898`.
The actual output is `397 178 157 26 679 57 898`

Comment: I think the issue is in your tree creation. For starters, if your root node is the midpoint of the sorted array, rounded up to the nearest index, then 397 is it. Given that, the result you are getting is a pre-ordered traversal of the resulting tree, although the tree isn't balanced. 26 < 157 < 178 < 397 (left side has no right branches), and 57 < 679 > 397 and 898 > 679 > 397 (right side is fine).

Comment: I guess the tree is balanced in the sense that it has the same number of nodes the the left and right of the root, so it might actually be totally fine except the root node isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The array wasn't sorted properly. I changed `narr.sort()`, to `narr = sorted(narr, key=int)`. Which sorted the array proberly.